# Android Studio - linking activies

Tags: java, android, kotlin, menu

I am new to Kotlin and I was able to get a navigation drawer working.  Here is the code but I have no idea how to make the menu items open  a new activity when clicked.

```
package com.example.navigationdrawer

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.Gravity
import android.view.MenuItem
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        setSupportActionBar(findViewById(R.id.toolbar))

        navigation_view.setNavigationItemSelectedListener{
            when (it.itemId) {
                R.id.nav_home -> {
                    true
                }
            }
            true
        }

        val drawerToggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, R.string.open, R.string.close)
        drawer.addDrawerListener(drawerToggle)
        drawerToggle.syncState()

        supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed()
        }
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
        return when (item.itemId) {
            android.R.id.home -> {
                drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
                true
            }
            else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
        }
    }
}
```

Here is  my main_menu.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_home"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
            android:title="@string/menu_home" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            android:title="@string/menu_gallery" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
            android:title="@string/menu_slideshow" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_tools"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"
            android:title="@string/menu_tools" />
    </group>

</menu>
```

I have been looking for hours and I can not find a tutorial that shows me how to accomplish this.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Since you are learning Navigation drawer, you can start with the basic implementation as shown here. https://abhiandroid.com/materialdesign/navigation-drawer. A different approach is using navigation graph as shown here https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui,  which needs you to know a lot more android concepts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using incorret id in your code
in you kotlin code you need to set listener to decide witch menu item is clicked like this :

```
 navView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener { menuItem ->
       when (menuItem.itemId) {
           R.id.nav_home -> {
               Toast.makeText(this, "Home", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
               true
           }
           R.id.nav_gallery -> {
               Toast.makeText(this, "Gallery", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
               true
           }
           R.id.nav_slideshow -> {
               Toast.makeText(this, "Slide show", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
               true
           }
           else -> {
               false
           }
       }
   }
```

}

for more detailed sample in kotlin check [this](https://medium.com/@ezichukwuamarachi/using-the-android-navigation-drawer-in-kotlin-6cf2cdd0e42f)

if you are using jetpack navigation component check [this](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-code-a-navigation-drawer-in-an-android-app--cms-30263)